# Incompatible types in stream Collectors.toList() in java

Tags: java, graph

I'm implementing graph representation.

```
Map<V, List<E<V>>> g = new HashMap<>();
```

one of methods in Graph class is

```
List<E<V>> getAllEdges() {
    List<E<V>> allEdges = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Map.Entry<V, List<E<V>>> entry: g.entrySet()) {
        allEdges.addAll(entry.getValue());
    }

    return allEdges;
}
```

But I'd like to make it shorter line using

```
List<E<V>> getAllEdges() {
    return  g.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

but I have an error such that

[image]

Is there a way to use stream for this?

Answer (score 6):

Since your values are already typed as `List<E<V>`, using `.collect(Collectors.toList())` is appropriate if you want to build a `List<List<E<V>>`.

To fix it, flatten the 2D list using `flatMap`:

```
List<E<V>> getAllEdges() {
    return  g.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```